# Naturality of product functor morphisms

Tags: category-theory

In https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/LN.pdf, page 10 the following is stated:

> Let us now assume that the product $B_1 \times B_2$ exists for every combination of $B_1$ and $B_2$. In this case, the definition of products is also functorial in $B_1$
> and $B_2$—both objects are totally passive in the description above. We capture this property by turning $\times$ into a functor of type $\mathscr{C} \times \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ . Indeed, there is
> a unique way to turn $\times$ into a functor so that the projection arrows, $\mathit{outl}$ and
> $\mathit{outr}$, are natural in $B_1$ and $B_2$:
> \begin{align*}
>   k_1 \cdot \mathit{outl}
>   &= \mathit{outl} \cdot (k_1 × k_2) \,,
>   \tag{13}
>   \\
>   k_2 \cdot \mathit{outr}
>   &= \mathit{outr} \cdot (k_1 × k_2) \,.
>   \tag{14}
> \end{align*}

In equations $(13)$ and $(14)$ it seems to me that $\mathit{outl}$ on the left of the equations is not the same $\mathit{outl}$ as on the right (likewise for $\mathit{outr}$).

I believe the $\mathit{outl}$ on the left goes from some object $A \times B$ to $A$, while the $\mathit{outl}$ on the right goes from $A' \times B'$ to $A'$, where $k_1$ goes from $A$ to $A'$. So, the equations maybe should have been written
$$
  k_1 \cdot \mathit{outl} = \mathit{outl}^{\,\prime} \cdot (k_1 \times k_2) \,.
$$

I am traveling and on a phone so please forgive the lack of a diagram. If anyone can confirm that the two appearances of $\mathit{outl}$ (and similarly $\mathit{outr}$) are actually not (necessarily) the same morphism, that would be great. I interjected necessarily since the diagram should still make sense if $k_1 \colon A \to A$ and $k_2 \colon B \to B$, but I believe the purpose of the equations was for general $k_1 \colon A \to A’$ and $k_2 \colon B \to B’$.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a kind of function name overloading. It is expected that the reader will be able to fill in the detail themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I believe your answer confirms my intuition regarding the domains/codomains of the two appearances of outl. Interestingly, the same page has some examples distinguishing outl and outl’ and other examples not doing so. I’m glad to know I was following the ideas correctly. I hope other self learners find this post useful since it can be frustrating when you are not certain if you are following the material. The paper referenced above is fantastic, but being able to verify my understanding in this forum is invaluable. Thanks again for the thoughtful answer.

Comment: For future reference, do not leave essential parts of the question in external links. That is my guess to why you were downvoted. That and not using mathjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

We have objects $B_1, B_2, B^{\,\prime}_1, B^{\,\prime}_2$ and consider two morphisms
$$
  k_1 \colon B_1 \longrightarrow B^{\,\prime}_1 \,,
  \quad
  k_2 \colon B_2 \longrightarrow B^{\,\prime}_2 \,.
$$
For the two products
$$
  \newcommand{\outl}{\mathrm{outl}}
  \newcommand{\outr}{\mathrm{outr}}
  (B_1 × B_2, \outl, \outr) \,,
  \qquad
  (B^{\,\prime}_1 × B^{\,\prime}_2, \outl', \outr')
$$
there then exists a unique morphism
$$
  k_1 × k_2
  \colon
  B_1 × B_2
  \longrightarrow
  B^{\,\prime}_1 × B^{\,\prime}_2
$$
such that the two equations
$$
  \outl' \cdot (k_1 × k_2) = k_1 \cdot \outl \,,
  \qquad
  \outr' \cdot (k_1 × k_2) = k_2 \cdot \outr \,,
$$
hold.
These two equations express that the diagram
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
    B_1  @<{\outl}<<  B_1 × B_2  @>{\outr}>>  B_2  \\
    @V{k_1}VV  @V{k_1 × k_2}VV  @V{k_2}VV  \\
    B^{\,\prime}_1  @<<{\outl'}<  B^{\,\prime}_1 × B^{\,\prime}_2  @>>{\outr'}>  B^{\,\prime}_2  \\
  \end{CD}
$$
needs to commute.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and for fixing my question so beautifully. I will definitely post that way in the future. Elsewhere, people explained that outl and outr are actually natural transformations. I think I see that as well, but I have to work out the details better since I would imagine there has to be some coherence between outl and outr.